# Nokia Lumia 610 Windows Live ID

Tags: store, microsoft-account, 7.x, nokia-lumia-610

I have tried to sign in with Windows Live ID but it didn't confirm as it's okay or not. Also, I want to install applications but I can't. Why is this? I'm using a Nokia Lumia 610.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a Nokia Lumia 610 and WP7.x.

As of the official [Windows Phone 7 support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/11696/windows-phone-7):

> Windows Phone 7 has reached end of support, so services and
>   functionality for this version of Windows will be discontinued over
>   time.

** *Download apps and games FAQ*,

> You may not have the latest version of the Windows Phone operating
>   system (OS) on your phone. You'll need Windows Phone 7.5 to download
>   and update apps.